# Memory Leaks in Jruby 1.7.0.preview1

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, memory-leaks, jruby

i have a jruby application which starts 200 Threads (Jruby 1.7.0.preview1). Each thread parsed a xml document and save the complex data in several mongodb collections. I'm using the Java Mongo Driver (version 2.7.3) to store data in mongodb. 
My JVM options for the applications are as followed:

```
-J-Djruby.thread.pooling=true -J-Xmn512m -J-Xms4096m -J-Xmx4096m -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=45 -J-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -J-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -J-XX:+PrintGCDetails -J-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -J-Xloggc:/LOGPATH/gc.log -J-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=60000 -J-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=60000
```

So everytime the threads are working and saving data in the specific collections my heapsize is on the limit of 4GB very fast. I've made a test with the jmap command and found out that many objects of java.util.LinkedHashMap were created (something about 1.300.000). 
I don't know if i can reduce the amount of this kind of objecttype.

Is there maybe a known issue with LinkedHashMaps and Memory Leaks in Jruby ?

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thx
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I have used Eclipse's [Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to successfully track down 3 memory leaks in my jruby on rails app in the past week.  I highly recommend it.  In none of the cases was the memory leak in jruby itself, but rather 2 of them were in Mongoid and once in my own app.  I've noticed, however, that jruby is more sensitive to memory leaks than MRI.

Also check out this [blog post](http://blog.headius.com/2010/07/finding-leaks-in-ruby-apps-with-eclipse.html) on using MAT to diagnose leaks in jruby.